# Компилирование GCC по Linux From Scratch - 3 ошибки

Tags: gcc, makefile, build-error

При попытке компилирования GCC (шаг первый) выходят такие ошибки:

```
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc...  /mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-8.2.0/build/./prev-gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-8.2.0/build/./prev-gcc/ -B/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-8.2.0/build/intl':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:8927: configure-stage2-intl] Ошибка 77
make[2]: выход из каталога «/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-8.2.0/build»
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21584: stage2-bubble] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-8.2.0/build»
make: *** [Makefile:897: all] Ошибка 2
```

Проблему так и не нашел, но если открыть config.log то в нем есть ссылка на файл confdefs.h и isl/schedule.h.

Если быть точнее то:

```
configure:5924: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -I$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp -I$$s/gmp -I$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpfr/src -I$$s/mpfr/src -I$$s/mpc/src     -lisl -L$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp/.libs -L$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpfr/src/.libs -L$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpc/src/.libs -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp conftest.c  -lisl -lgmp >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:5924: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <isl/schedule.h>
| int
| main ()
| {
| isl_options_set_schedule_serialize_sccs (NULL, 0);
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
```

Я пытался найти похожие ошибки, но это было бессмысленно.

Кстати, содержание файла config.log

```
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##


/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown



## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2304: checking build system type
configure:2318: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2365: checking host system type
configure:2378: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2398: checking target system type
configure:2411: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2465: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2533: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2544: checking whether ln works
configure:2566: result: yes
configure:2570: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2574: result: yes
configure:2581: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2645: result: /bin/sed
configure:2654: checking for gawk
configure:2670: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2681: result: gawk
configure:3212: checking for libitm support
configure:3222: result: yes
configure:3231: checking for libsanitizer support
configure:3241: result: yes
configure:3289: checking for libhsail-rt support
configure:3301: result: yes
configure:4008: checking for gcc
configure:4024: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4035: result: gcc
configure:4264: checking for C compiler version
configure:4273: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4284: $? = 0
configure:4273: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.2.0 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 
configure:4284: $? = 0
configure:4273: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4284: $? = 1
configure:4273: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4284: $? = 1
configure:4304: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4326: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:4330: $? = 0
configure:4367: result: a.out
configure:4383: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4392: ./a.out
configure:4396: $? = 0
configure:4411: result: yes
configure:4418: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:4420: result: no
configure:4423: checking for suffix of executables
configure:4430: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:4434: $? = 0
configure:4456: result: 
configure:4462: checking for suffix of object files
configure:4484: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:4488: $? = 0
configure:4509: result: o
configure:4513: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:4532: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:4532: $? = 0
configure:4541: result: yes
configure:4550: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:4570: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:4570: $? = 0
configure:4611: result: yes
configure:4628: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:4692: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4692: $? = 0
configure:4705: result: none needed
configure:4783: checking for g++
configure:4799: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:4810: result: g++
configure:4837: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:4846: g++ --version >&5
g++ (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0
configure:4857: $? = 0
configure:4846: g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.2.0 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 
configure:4857: $? = 0
configure:4846: g++ -V >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4857: $? = 1
configure:4846: g++ -qversion >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4857: $? = 1
configure:4861: checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler
configure:4880: g++ -c   conftest.cpp >&5
configure:4880: $? = 0
configure:4889: result: yes
configure:4898: checking whether g++ accepts -g
configure:4918: g++ -c -g  conftest.cpp >&5
configure:4918: $? = 0
configure:4959: result: yes
configure:5008: checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
configure:5025: g++ -o conftest -g -O2   -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc conftest.cpp  >&5
configure:5025: $? = 0
configure:5026: result: yes
configure:5090: checking for gnatbind
configure:5120: result: no
configure:5182: checking for gnatmake
configure:5212: result: no
configure:5231: checking whether compiler driver understands Ada
configure:5254: result: no
configure:5263: checking how to compare bootstrapped objects
configure:5288: result: cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
configure:5348: checking for objdir
configure:5363: result: .libs
configure:5911: checking for isl 0.15 or later
configure:5924: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -I$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp -I$$s/gmp -I$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpfr/src -I$$s/mpfr/src -I$$s/mpc/src     -lisl -L$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp/.libs -L$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpfr/src/.libs -L$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpc/src/.libs -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp conftest.c  -lisl -lgmp >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:5924: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <isl/schedule.h>
| int
| main ()
| {
| isl_options_set_schedule_serialize_sccs (NULL, 0);
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:5931: result: no
configure:5935: result: required isl version is 0.15 or later
configure:7028: checking for default BUILD_CONFIG
configure:7060: result: bootstrap-debug
configure:7065: checking for --enable-vtable-verify
configure:7078: result: no
configure:7678: checking for bison
configure:7694: found /usr/bin/bison
configure:7705: result: bison -y
configure:7725: checking for bison
configure:7741: found /usr/bin/bison
configure:7752: result: bison
configure:7772: checking for gm4
configure:7802: result: no
configure:7772: checking for gnum4
configure:7802: result: no
configure:7772: checking for m4
configure:7788: found /usr/bin/m4
configure:7799: result: m4
configure:7819: checking for flex
configure:7835: found /usr/bin/flex
configure:7846: result: flex
configure:7867: checking for flex
configure:7883: found /usr/bin/flex
configure:7894: result: flex
configure:7914: checking for makeinfo
configure:7930: found /usr/bin/makeinfo
configure:7941: result: makeinfo
configure:7975: checking for expect
configure:8005: result: no
configure:8024: checking for runtest
configure:8054: result: no
configure:8169: checking for ar
configure:8185: found /usr/bin/ar
configure:8196: result: ar
configure:8310: checking for as
configure:8326: found /usr/bin/as
configure:8337: result: as
configure:8451: checking for dlltool
configure:8481: result: no
configure:8592: checking for ld
configure:8608: found /usr/bin/ld
configure:8619: result: ld
configure:8733: checking for lipo
configure:8763: result: no
configure:8874: checking for nm
configure:8890: found /usr/bin/nm
configure:8901: result: nm
configure:9015: checking for ranlib
configure:9031: found /usr/bin/ranlib
configure:9042: result: ranlib
configure:9151: checking for strip
configure:9167: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:9178: result: strip
configure:9287: checking for windres
configure:9317: result: no
configure:9428: checking for windmc
configure:9458: result: no
configure:9569: checking for objcopy
configure:9585: found /usr/bin/objcopy
configure:9596: result: objcopy
configure:9710: checking for objdump
configure:9726: found /usr/bin/objdump
configure:9737: result: objdump
configure:9851: checking for readelf
configure:9867: found /usr/bin/readelf
configure:9878: result: readelf
configure:10031: checking for cc
configure:10047: found /usr/bin/cc
configure:10058: result: cc
configure:10192: checking for c++
configure:10208: found /usr/bin/c++
configure:10219: result: c++
configure:10353: checking for gcc
configure:10369: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:10380: result: gcc
configure:10509: checking for gfortran
configure:10539: result: no
configure:10670: checking for gccgo
configure:10700: result: no
configure:10761: checking for ar
configure:10779: found /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ar
configure:10791: result: /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ar
configure:10991: checking for as
configure:11009: found /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as
configure:11021: result: /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as
configure:11221: checking for dlltool
configure:11254: result: no
configure:11371: checking for dlltool
configure:11401: result: no
configure:11451: checking for ld
configure:11469: found /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld
configure:11481: result: /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld
configure:11681: checking for lipo
configure:11714: result: no
configure:11831: checking for lipo
configure:11861: result: no
configure:11911: checking for nm
configure:11929: found /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/nm
configure:11941: result: /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/nm
configure:12141: checking for objcopy
configure:12159: found /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/objcopy
configure:12171: result: /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/objcopy
configure:12371: checking for objdump
configure:12389: found /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/objdump
configure:12401: result: /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/objdump
configure:12601: checking for ranlib
configure:12619: found /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ranlib
configure:12631: result: /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ranlib
configure:12831: checking for readelf
configure:12849: found /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/readelf
configure:12861: result: /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/readelf
configure:13061: checking for strip
configure:13079: found /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/strip
configure:13091: result: /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/strip
configure:13291: checking for windres
configure:13324: result: no
configure:13441: checking for windres
configure:13471: result: no
configure:13521: checking for windmc
configure:13554: result: no
configure:13671: checking for windmc
configure:13701: result: no
configure:13729: checking where to find the target ar
configure:13757: result: pre-installed in /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin
configure:13771: checking where to find the target as
configure:13799: result: pre-installed in /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin
configure:13813: checking where to find the target cc
configure:13836: result: just compiled
configure:13855: checking where to find the target c++
configure:13881: result: just compiled
configure:13900: checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++
configure:13926: result: just compiled
configure:13945: checking where to find the target dlltool
configure:13978: result: host tool
configure:13987: checking where to find the target gcc
configure:14010: result: just compiled
configure:14029: checking where to find the target gfortran
configure:14065: result: host tool
configure:14074: checking where to find the target gccgo
configure:14110: result: host tool
configure:14119: checking where to find the target ld
configure:14147: result: pre-installed in /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin
configure:14161: checking where to find the target lipo
configure:14183: result: host tool
configure:14192: checking where to find the target nm
configure:14220: result: pre-installed in /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin
configure:14234: checking where to find the target objcopy
configure:14262: result: pre-installed in /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin
configure:14276: checking where to find the target objdump
configure:14304: result: pre-installed in /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin
configure:14318: checking where to find the target ranlib
configure:14346: result: pre-installed in /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin
configure:14360: checking where to find the target readelf
configure:14388: result: pre-installed in /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin
configure:14402: checking where to find the target strip
configure:14430: result: pre-installed in /tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin
configure:14444: checking where to find the target windres
configure:14477: result: host tool
configure:14486: checking where to find the target windmc
configure:14519: result: host tool
configure:14556: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:14565: result: no
configure:14796: creating ./config.status

## ---------------------- ##
## Running config.status. ##
## ---------------------- ##

This file was extended by config.status, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  CONFIG_FILES    = 
  CONFIG_HEADERS  = 
  CONFIG_LINKS    = 
  CONFIG_COMMANDS = 
  $ ./config.status 

on dappinc-pc

config.status:978: creating Makefile

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='ar'
AR_FOR_BUILD='$(AR)'
AR_FOR_TARGET='/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ar'
AS='as'
AS_FOR_BUILD='$(AS)'
AS_FOR_TARGET='/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/as'
AWK='gawk'
BISON='bison'
BUILD_CONFIG='bootstrap-debug'
CC='gcc'
CC_FOR_BUILD='$(CC)'
CC_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/xgcc -B$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/'
CFLAGS='-g -O2'
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD='-g -O2'
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET='-g -O2'
COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/as'
COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/collect-ld'
COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/nm'
CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++ -std=gnu++98'
CXXFLAGS='-g -O2'
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD='-g -O2'
CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET='-g -O2'
CXX_FOR_BUILD='$(CXX)'
CXX_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/xg++ -B$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/ -nostdinc++ `if test -f $$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libstdc++-v3/scripts/testsuite_flags; then $(SHELL) $$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libstdc++-v3/scripts/testsuite_flags --build-includes; else echo -funconfigured-libstdc++-v3 ; fi` -L$$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libstdc++-v3/src -L$$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L$$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs'
DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
DEFS='-DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\"'
DLLTOOL='dlltool'
DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='$(DLLTOOL)'
DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET='$(DLLTOOL)'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPECT='expect'
FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=' -B$(build_tooldir)/bin/ -B$(build_tooldir)/lib/ -isystem $(build_tooldir)/include -isystem $(build_tooldir)/sys-include'
FLEX='flex'
GCC_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/xgcc -B$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/'
GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
GDB_TK=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='$(GFORTRAN)'
GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET='$(GFORTRAN)'
GNATBIND='no'
GNATMAKE='no'
GOC_FOR_BUILD='$(GOC)'
GOC_FOR_TARGET='$(GOC)'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LD='ld'
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
LD_FOR_BUILD='$(LD)'
LD_FOR_TARGET='/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld'
LEX='flex'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO='lipo'
LIPO_FOR_TARGET='$(LIPO)'
LN='ln'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4='m4'
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='makeinfo'
NM='nm'
NM_FOR_BUILD='$(NM)'
NM_FOR_TARGET='/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/nm'
OBJCOPY='objcopy'
OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET='/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/objcopy'
OBJDUMP='objdump'
OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET='/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/objdump'
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB='ranlib'
RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='$(RANLIB)'
RANLIB_FOR_TARGET='/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ranlib'
RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET='$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc/xgcc -shared-libgcc -B$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gcc -nostdinc++ -L$$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libstdc++-v3/src -L$$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L$$r/$(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs'
READELF='readelf'
READELF_FOR_TARGET='/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/readelf'
RPATH_ENVVAR='LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
RUNTEST='runtest'
SED='/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='strip'
STRIP_FOR_TARGET='/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/strip'
SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='../configure --target= --prefix=/tools --with-glibc-version=2.11 --with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs --with-newlib --without-headers --with-local-prefix=/tools --with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-multilib --disable-decimal-float --disable-threads --disable-libatomic --disable-libgomp --disable-libmpx --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libvtv --disable-libstdcxx --enable-languages=c,c++'
WINDMC='windmc'
WINDMC_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDMC)'
WINDMC_FOR_TARGET='$(WINDMC)'
WINDRES='windres'
WINDRES_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDRES)'
WINDRES_FOR_TARGET='$(WINDRES)'
YACC='bison -y'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_configargs=' --cache-file=./config.cache '\''--prefix=/tools'\'' '\''--with-glibc-version=2.11'\'' '\''--with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs'\'' '\''--with-newlib'\'' '\''--without-headers'\'' '\''--with-local-prefix=/tools'\'' '\''--with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include'\'' '\''--disable-nls'\'' '\''--disable-shared'\'' '\''--disable-multilib'\'' '\''--disable-decimal-float'\'' '\''--disable-threads'\'' '\''--disable-libatomic'\'' '\''--disable-libgomp'\'' '\''--disable-libmpx'\'' '\''--disable-libquadmath'\'' '\''--disable-libssp'\'' '\''--disable-libvtv'\'' '\''--disable-libstdcxx'\'' '\''--enable-languages=c,c++,lto'\'' --program-transform-name='\''s,y,y,'\'' --disable-option-checking'
build_configdirs=' libiberty libcpp fixincludes'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_libsubdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_subdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_tooldir='${exec_prefix}/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
compare_exclusions='gcc/cc*-checksum$(objext) | gcc/ada/*tools/*'
configdirs=' intl libiberty zlib libbacktrace libcpp libdecnumber gmp mpfr mpc fixincludes gcc libcc1 lto-plugin'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
do_compare='cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='${prefix}'
extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags='--enable-shared'
extra_host_zlib_configure_flags=''
extra_isl_gmp_configure_flags='--with-gmp-builddir=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp'
extra_liboffloadmic_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_flags=''
extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags='--with-gmp-include=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp --with-gmp-lib=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp/.libs'
extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags='--with-mpfr-include=$$s/mpfr/src --with-mpfr-lib=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpfr/src/.libs'
extra_mpfr_configure_flags='--with-gmp-include=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp --with-gmp-lib=$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp/.libs'
get_gcc_base_ver='cat'
gmpinc='-I$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp -I$$s/gmp -I$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpfr/src -I$$s/mpfr/src -I$$s/mpc/src '
gmplibs='-L$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/gmp/.libs -L$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpfr/src/.libs -L$$r/$(HOST_SUBDIR)/mpc/src/.libs -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp'
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_configargs=' --cache-file=./config.cache  '\''--prefix=/tools'\'' '\''--with-glibc-version=2.11'\'' '\''--with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs'\'' '\''--with-newlib'\'' '\''--without-headers'\'' '\''--with-local-prefix=/tools'\'' '\''--with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include'\'' '\''--disable-nls'\'' '\''--disable-shared'\'' '\''--disable-multilib'\'' '\''--disable-decimal-float'\'' '\''--disable-threads'\'' '\''--disable-libatomic'\'' '\''--disable-libgomp'\'' '\''--disable-libmpx'\'' '\''--disable-libquadmath'\'' '\''--disable-libssp'\'' '\''--disable-libvtv'\'' '\''--disable-libstdcxx'\'' '\''--enable-languages=c,c++,lto'\'' --program-transform-name='\''s,y,y,'\'' --disable-option-checking'
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_shared='no'
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
islinc=''
isllibs=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
poststage1_ldflags='-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
poststage1_libs=''
prefix='/tools'
program_transform_name='s,y,y,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stage1_cflags='-g'
stage1_checking='--enable-checking=yes,types'
stage1_languages='c,c++,lto'
stage1_ldflags='-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
stage1_libs=''
stage2_werror_flag=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_configargs='--cache-file=./config.cache   '\''--prefix=/tools'\'' '\''--with-glibc-version=2.11'\'' '\''--with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs'\'' '\''--with-newlib'\'' '\''--without-headers'\'' '\''--with-local-prefix=/tools'\'' '\''--with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include'\'' '\''--disable-nls'\'' '\''--disable-shared'\'' '\''--disable-multilib'\'' '\''--disable-decimal-float'\'' '\''--disable-threads'\'' '\''--disable-libatomic'\'' '\''--disable-libgomp'\'' '\''--disable-libmpx'\'' '\''--disable-libquadmath'\'' '\''--disable-libssp'\'' '\''--disable-libvtv'\'' '\''--disable-libstdcxx'\'' '\''--enable-languages=c,c++,lto'\'' --program-transform-name='\''s,y,y,'\'' --disable-option-checking'
target_configdirs=' libgcc'
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_subdir='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_vendor='pc'
tooldir='${exec_prefix}/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

alphaieee_frag='/dev/null'
host_makefile_frag='/dev/null'
ospace_frag='/dev/null'
serialization_dependencies='serdep.tmp'
target_makefile_frag='../config/mt-gnu'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"

configure: exit 0
```

Comment: ошибка: *cannot find -lmpc*. установите пакет(ы), содержащий эту библиотеку — `libmpc.so`. для debian и наследников достаточно установить `libmpc-dev`: вместе с зависимостями установится всё что требуется.

Comment: Ошибку исправил, но теперь новая ошибка: `/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/tools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory`